# Why won't relative path work for xsl:include?

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I have a XSL file, which converts to PDF.  On the top of this page, I have a very long CSS style such as

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="Header">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">
        <xsl:value-of select="$font-size"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
...
```

It takes a long time to render so that I copy these into a new page (PDF_style.xsl) in another location.  Then I use

```
<xsl:include href="../allStyles/PDF_style.xsl"/>
```

But when I test it, the system says it couldn't file this file location!

Note: allStyles is the folder I store every stylesheet files and the path is a correct one.

Is `<xsl:include href="..." />` a correct way to link an external file?  Or do I have to use something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A relative path for `xsl:include/@href` or `xsl:import/@href` is **resolved against the directory of the XSLT file that does the including or importing**.

So, if your XSLT file is

```
/xslt/my.xsl
```

then the `PDF_style.xsl` file must be here:

```
/allStyles/PDF_style.xsl
```

in order for

```
<xsl:include href="../allStyles/PDF_style.xsl" />
```

to be correct in `/xslt/my.xsl`.

Comment: Thank you very much, kjhughes for your help!  It is working now.